# Extract JSON response from REST API

Tags: php, json, ionic-framework, jwt

My API returns the following JSON response:

```
[{"result":{"status":1,"message":"Token generated successfully","stoken":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjVmMXoyaTNhbDJ4eCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9lc2FsZXMuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiZVNhbGVzIiwianRpIjoiNWYxejJpM2FsMnh4IiwiaWF0IjoxNDczODMwNDExLCJuYmYiOjE0NzM4MzA0NzEsImV4cCI6MTQ3MzgzNDAxMSwidWlkIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJ1Z3JwIjoic2FsZXMifQ.eeFU68UdAIkZuWtSK8H0mfJRsGM0aaCdZ2MJX4ZQUF0"}}]
```

My code in Ionic:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http ) {
    $scope.data = {}; 

    $scope.submit = function(){
        var link = 'http://myapi.com/jwt/auth/';

        $http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username, password : $scope.data.password})
        .success(function(data, status, headers,config){
            $scope.response = data; // for UI

            var jsParse = JSON.parse(data)      

            //how to retrieve the 'stoken' value from the JSON ?


        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers,config){
          console.log('data error');
        })
        .then(function (res){
            $scope.response = res.data;

        });
    };
}])
```

PHP code that generate the json:

```
    $responses[] = array('result'=> 
                    array( 'status' => 1, 
                           'message' => 'Token generated successfully', 
                           'stoken' => ''.$token,
                        )
                    );

    //return json_encode(['result' => 1, 'message' => 'Token generated successfully', 'token' => '' . $token,]);
     return json_encode($responses);
```

1. How can I retrieve the 'stoken' value from the JSON ?
2. How can I loop through the JSON if it has multiple 'result' entries?

Comment: in JS you can access via Index: `jsParse['stoken']`

Comment: the json return in  >>  [{\"result\":{\"status\":1,\"message\":\"Token generated successfully\",\"stoken\":\"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjVmMXoyaTNhbDJ4eCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9lc2FsZXMuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiZVNhbGVzIiwianRpIjoiNWYxejJpM2FsMnh4IiwiaWF0IjoxNDczODQ4OTk1LCJuYmYiOjE0NzM4NDkwNTUsImV4cCI6MTQ3Mzg1MjU5NSwidWlkIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJ1Z3JwIjoic2FsZXMifQ.MJLIYAslvJp_rSmPUEnFK7ZjYLx2tv8ydhTY3nYtbRA\"}}]   <<  there are slash added to each quotation, would be cause invalid json ?

Comment: the **data** you are trying to parse (`var jsParse = JSON.Parse(data);` is already JSON. So you only need to do `var token = data['stoken];`. Sory for missleading you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username, password : $scope.data.password})
        .success(function(data, status, headers,config){
            $scope.response = data;
  
            $scope.stoken =  $scope.response[0].result.stoken;
        


        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers,config){
          console.log('data error');
        })
        .then(function (res){
            $scope.response = res.data;

        });
```

There is no required of `JSON.parse`, angular uses http intercepters which automatically do this for you, and your response object already contain the JSON object.

Comment: from console >>> $scope.response[0].result is undefined .  I have added my PHP code to the question.

Comment: `function success(response){
 $scope.stoken = response.data[0].result.stoken; 
}` try this.